# Could / should I flag spam bot user?

Tags: support

Just saw [generic spam comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/are-there-any-drawbacks-to-install-intensedebate-on-my-blog/8626#8626) from [clearly spam account](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2973/fibonacci-indicator).

Comments can be flagged, is there any mechanism to report user accounts? Or should I ignore accounts and only report their posts?

Comment: Interesting: because this user is not registered, [you cannot search for it](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/376/cannot-search-for-unregistered-user), so except for this question there are no links to the user page and thus the effect of the spam link is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot flag a user specifically, but if they have ever authored a post, you can flag the post to explain your concerns about the user. Failing that, I would suggest sending an email to the "contact us" address linked in the footer of every page.

Comment: What would be criteria to use "contact us" option? Is situation like described enough or is it too minor to waste everyone's time and contact should be reserved for more radical cases of spam?

Comment: @Rarst I'm not seeing any "spam comments" in the linked post (maybe removed) so it's hard to say. Use your best judgment. An email message calling someone into the site is certainly an escalation up from voting or commenting or flagging. I wouldn't expect an email for every every little persnickety problem, but I don't know how to codify that line of "too minor." Just use your best judgment.

Comment: Yep, comment was already deleted by moderator. Noted on _best judgment_, works for me.